# Reset a listviewitem which is linked to listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a listview which is bound to a listviewitem as you will see below - problem is I need to clear out the database on a timer and start from scratch,

I know to clear the listview I just do

```
listview.items.clear()
```

problem is I need to also clear the listviewitem or it is going to rebind the same information to the listview.

declared:

```
    Dim TempStr(7) As String
    Dim TempNode As ListViewItem
```

problematic statement:

```
            listview2.items.clear() 
            For pop As Integer = 0 To pendrun.Rows.Count - 1
            TempStr(0) = pendrun.Rows(pop)("RID")
            Select Case pendrun.Rows(pop)("Utype")
                Case 1
                    TempStr(1) = "BLS Ambulance"
                Case 2
                    TempStr(1) = "ALS Ambulance"
                Case 3
                    TempStr(1) = "SCT Ambulance"
                Case 4
                    TempStr(1) = "Wheelchair Van"
                Case 5
                    TempStr(1) = "Taxi"
            End Select

            Select Case pendrun.Rows(pop)("Curgency")
                Case 1
                    TempStr(2) = "Scheduled"
                Case 2
                    TempStr(2) = "Non-Scheduled"
                Case 3
                    TempStr(2) = "ASAP"
                Case 4
                    TempStr(2) = "STAT"
            End Select
            TempStr(3) = pendrun.Rows(pop)("Pname")
            TempStr(4) = pendrun.Rows(pop)("Texttime")
            TempStr(5) = pendrun.Rows(pop)("sname") & " - " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("sfaddress") & ", " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("sfcity") & ", " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("sfstate")
            TempStr(6) = pendrun.Rows(pop)("dname") & " - " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("dfaddress") & ", " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("dfcity") & ", " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("dfstate")
            TempNode = New ListViewItem(TempStr)
            ListView2.Items.Add(TempNode)
            next
```

How do I flush all data from tempnode?

I did find

```
TempNode.SubItems.clear()
```

but this does not appear to work

Comment: Try TempNode.Items.Clear()

Comment: items is not a valid subcategory for listviewitem classes

Comment: `TempNode.SubItems.clear()` is the correct syntax, perhaps the problem is how/where you invoke it...it isnt shown in the problematic code where you call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code does not show where, when or how you try to remove the subitems.  Based on the Title, I'm guessing that the LVI is already assigned to the ListView, so doing stuff to TempNode might not do anything (it could be a different LVI by this time.)

`ListViewItem.SubItems.Clear()` is the correct syntax but this will also remove the `Item.Label` So:

```
 ' preserve "Label" and put it back:
 Dim txt As String = LV.SelectedItems(0).Text
 LV.SelectedItems(0).SubItems.Clear()
 LV.SelectedItems(0).Text = txt
```

or reference as `LV.Items(IndexOfTheItemToClear).Text`

another way:

```
    ' loop BACKWARDS to remove all but the last subitem (index = 0)
    For n As Integer = LV.SelectedItems(0).SubItems.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1

        LV.SelectedItems(0).SubItems.RemoveAt(n)

    Next
```

since you are removing things from the collection you are looping on, you have to loop backwards otherwise your code runs out of items before `N` is reached.

EDIT

Your question is not nearly as clear as you might think it is.  If you are trying to remove the Item represented by TempNode in the code, you have to find it and remove it.  Once TempNode has been added to the LV, you cannot recreate TempNode (`TempNode = New ListViewItem(TempStr)`) because NEW makes a **new** ListViewItem which is not the same as the one you added earlier.  So, you need to find the old one and remove it (not the same as `clear[ing] the entire listview` or `flush all data from tempnode`.  So:

```
' presumably 'pendrun.Rows(pop)("RID")' is the item text, so find it:
Dim search As String = pendrun.Rows(pop)("RID")

For n as integer = 0 to LV.Items.Count - 1
    if LV.Items(n).Text = search then
        LV.Items.RemoveAt(n)
        Exit For
    End iF
Next n
```

It wont clear the LV but will find a specific item and remove it and the associated ListViewItem.SubItems from the LV.  Matching on Text is pretty weak, so if you have something more unique like an ID, you can store that as a subitem and search that way:

```
 if LV.Items(n).SubItems(WhereYouPutIt).Text = search then...
```

or even stash it in the `ListViewItem.Tag` property:

```
if LV.Items(n).Tag = search then...
```

Comment: I am not trying to delete any single item I am trying to clear the entire listview and any file holding data associated with it so my timer can tick again and run the same fetching code and not have the same data Plus the new data show when the timer ticks again, I successfully cleared the listview with listview2.items.clear() which happened right before this for statement was called

Comment: well, as in your post, `listview.items.clear()` will clear the entire ListView of all ListViewItems...your code will have to handle clearing data files we have no way of knowing what is going on there.

Comment: as I stated in the question the only question is how to clear the content of Tempnode (the listviewitem) which I have identified to be carrying over information to the next run

Comment: `Tempnode = nothing` will absolutely do it...wont affect the LV at all though as per comment #1 here: "`I am trying to clear the entire listview`" ... 2 different things